# Retaining Column Ordering Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have synapse analytics notebook. I am reading a csv file to a pyspark dataframe. Now when i write this dataframe to json file, then the the column order changes to Alphabetical order. Can some help me how i can retain the column order with out hardcoding the column names in the notebook.

For example when i do `df.show()` I am getting `BCol, CCol,ACol`

Now when i write to json file it is writing as `{ACol ='';BCol='';CCol=''}`. I am not able to retain the values.

I am using the following code to write to json file

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save(dest_location)
```

Comment: Are you talking about order of json attributes or really the column order? AFAIK dataframe will retain order from source, and in fact you'll have to explicitly use a `select` with different order if you wanna change the order. Can you post concrete example with code?

Comment: I am talking about json attributes. For example when i  do df.show()  i am getting BCol, CCol,ACol. Now when i write to json file it is writing as {ACol ='';BCol='';CCol=''}. I am not able to retain the values. I am using the following code to write to json file ``` df.coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save(dest_location)```

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example with some test data?

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example with code, input, current output and expected/desired output then someone might be able to help.

Comment: Input file(csv) has column  ApplicationNo,StudentName,Address1,Batch Columns. I had read that file using -> df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv(input_path) and then i had done some transformations and then write the file to json to output path using df.write.mode("overwrite").json(op_path) and when i check in the output path i see the columns are reordered like Address1,ApplicationNo,Batch,StudentName. Now when i read the json file using the df = spark.read.option("header",True).json(op_path) and when i see the display(df), then i see the order - Address1,ApplicationNo,Batch,StudentName.